# Create a 'single' page for a Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types

Ok, I installed the Custom Post Type UI plugin and create one. I then added a new post to it. In my theme, i have a piece of code like this:

```
<?php 
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_type' => 'case studies',   /* edit this line */
        'posts_per_page' => 15 ) );
?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>  

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
    </a>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Now, firstly if i click the thumbnail, i get an error in the browser saying it's in a redirect loop, but secondly I'd like to know exactly what files i need to create to view a single post of this custom post type. And what to put in that file.

Comment: man, my website dont open in the single. Helpe me please.

Comment: @WashingtonLuiz I converted your answer into a comment, do not post new questions as solutions.  Unfortunately, this is something that would need to be debugged further and not fit for the answers section. I would recommend asking your question over at the [WordPress Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/forums/).

Answer (score 21):

Use `single-{posttype}.php` for the single template. Also, if you register your post type with the `has_archive` argument set to `true`, then you can use `archive-{posttype}.php` for your archive template, which will allow you to skip that query that you have there, since the global `$wp_query` object will already be populated with your custom post type.

BTW, you have a space in your `post_type` argument, which will be a problem.

Check out the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), and consider [registering your CPTs using code](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) in a plugin rather than using a CPT UI plugin.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need as WordPress will use the default page template however you can create a custom [single-cpt.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display) file where cpt is the name of your [registered post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Usage).

```
<?php

get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
            <?php
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    // Include the page content template.
                    get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

                endwhile;
            ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- #main-content -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Comment: and where to put the file single-cpt.php ?

Comment: In your child theme folder, cpt being the name of your custom post type.

Comment: What if I don't have access to Theme folder and I have to manage everything in a plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

You could just write this into your single.php file (within the loop) and echo out whatever fields you need within the if statement.

```
if($post_type == 'case_studies') { // you may need this to be without spaces (machine name)

                echo '<h1>'.get_the_title().' flavors</h1>';

               // post id
             $post_id = get_the_ID();
              get_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_field_name', true);


                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a> 
                  <?php endwhile; ?>

 }
```

Another option is t0 create a page template. Copy your single.php file and rename it case_studies.php .. at the top within php tags add:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Brand Output 04/12
*/
?>
```

and then add the same if statement within the single.php loop as the above example...

Comment: Thsi works, but it is bad, bad practice, the nearest you should ever get to this is `get_template_part('stuff',$post->post_type);`

Comment: can you explain why it is bad practice?

Comment: Because it's unclean code, and you have a tonne of if else statements, and duplicated code. You would be better creating a template file like 'content.php', and doing `get_template_part('content',$post_type);` and using `content-case_studies.php` to override it on a per post type basis

Comment: That way your single.php remains readable. Even then it would eb better ot do it the proper way and use `single-case_studies.php`

Comment: cool. I changed the code in my theme to reflect this new method for outputting custom post types. thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

Custom Post Type in wordpress.Basic four steps.Step1: File Path location : theme/function.php in your theme.Paste code in function.php (register custom post type )

```
<?php

add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type_func' );
function custom_post_type_func() {
    //posttypename = services
$labels = array(
'name' => _x( 'Services', 'services' ),
'singular_name' => _x( 'services', 'services' ),
'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'services' ),
'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New services', 'services' ),
'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit services', 'services' ),
'new_item' => _x( 'New services', 'services' ),
'view_item' => _x( 'View services', 'services' ),
'search_items' => _x( 'Search services', 'services' ),
'not_found' => _x( 'No services found', 'services' ),
'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No services found in Trash', 'services' ),
'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent services:', 'services' ),
'menu_name' => _x( 'Services', 'services' ),
);
$args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'hierarchical' => true,
'description' => 'Hi, this is my custom post type.',
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag', 'page-category' ),
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => true,
'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'has_archive' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'can_export' => true,
'rewrite' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post'
);
register_post_type( 'services', $args );
}
?>
```

Step2: how can show wordpress custom post type in wordpress template page ?

You can show anywhere in template page like this :

```
<?php   $args = array( 'post_type' => 'services', 'posts_per_page' => 20 );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="services-items">
            <?php the_title(); 
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $post->post_title ) . '">';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' );
        echo '</a>'; }

?>
            </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Step3: Create new template for show single post like this

single-{custom post type name}.php
       or
single-services.php

Step4: Paste code in single-services.php file

```
 <?php /* The loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="main-post-div">
                <div class="single-page-post-heading">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="content-here">
                <?php  the_content();  ?>
                </div>
                <div class="comment-section-here"
                <?php //comments_template(); ?>
                </div>
                </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

This is  custom post type example with single post page.